# relation betwen Convexity and Incressing of function

Tags: analysis

Let $f :\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ and we are going to fix $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
and we define a new function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $\phi(x)=\frac{f(u+xv)-f(u)}{x}$.
the question is  to prove that if $F$ is convex so $\phi$ increasing.

I have a question this text is true or false because I choose the convex function can I get a contradiction.

when we take $F(x)=e^{x}$ and we fixe any $u,v$ we have function is not incrssing in $]0;1[$

Comment: $\phi$ is increasing in your example.

Comment: for exmaple take u=v=0 we get $\phi$ is decrsing anthor chosse $u=0$ $v=1$

Comment: Increasing does not mean strictly increasing. If $u=v=0$ then $\phi (x)\equiv 0$ which makes it both increasing and decreasing.

Comment: Do you understand that $u$ and $v$ are fixed and we have prove that $\phi$ is an increasing function of $x$ on $(0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 1):

If $0<x_1<x_2$ then $u+x_1v=(1-\frac {x_1}{x_2})u+\frac {x_1}{x_2}(u+x_2v)$. Hence,

$f(u+x_1v)\leq (1-\frac {x_1}{x_2})f(u)+\frac {x_1}{x_2}f(u+x_2v)$. Simple algebraic manipulation of this gives $\phi (x_1) \leq \phi (x_2)$.